# Java Syntax confusion, calling a variables method?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I have a class `Ball`, within it a variable `velocity` which is a `Vector`, declared as:

```
private Vector velocity;
```

Now somewhere else in the class, there is a function called `bounce`, declared as:

```
public void bounce(float surfaceTangent) {
    velocity = velocity.bounce(surfaceTangent);
}
```

I don't understand what that line assigning the `velocity` is doing, its unfamiliar syntax to me.  It looks like its calling velocity's `bounce` function, but `velocity` is a variable, not a class. It doesn't have a function at all...  What exactly is this doing?

Comment: Except for the so-called primitives (`boolean`, `int`, `float`, etc) every object (the value of a variable) in Java is an *instance* of some class.

Comment: This is indeed strange, since [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) does not have a `bounce()` method. I would expect `Ball` to have a `bounce()` method.

Comment: @PM77-1 It is probably not the List Vector, but rather a class that stores the vector of motion in physics (i.e. direction and speed). @bock.steve velocity is an instance of a class. Many times, you may have to reassign an object to another, or even change an object based on itself. For example, `myString = myString.trim();` trims myString of all whitespace and stores it back in myString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is an instance of class Vector (confusing name here because most people would associate that type name with java.util.Vector), which has instance methods and instance variables that belong to every instance of Vector. Bounce looks like an instance method here. In object oriented programming you usually interact with objects (instances) through their methods.

> but velocity is a variable, not a class. It doesn't have a function at all...

In Java, classes do have their own class methods (and class variables), these are denoted by the method modifier of static.

Comment: Are you saying that `bounce()` is an existing method of `ava.util.Vector<E>`?

Comment: @PM77-1 No. There's nothing in his code example that shows that his Vector class is java.util.Vector, and seeing how he's modifying existing code that we assume here works, Vector here is obviously not java.util.Vector.

Comment: Not a bad choice of name if you're writing code to model the motion of physical objects, but it might have saved me five seconds or so of cogitation if the example had started with `import mumble.physics.Vector;`

Comment: Yes this is it, I looked through the rest of the code and buried deep in some corner, there was a new Vector class, with a bounce method.  So yes, it was calling a bounce method in the Vector class!

Comment: @bock.steve If you are using an IDE chances are you can hold ctrl and click on the type name to go directly to the declaration of Vector.

Comment: @jameslarge I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable declared called `velocity` to which you are assigning value returned by the method `bounce(float)` invoked on the velocity instance.